# How to Install Imagick PHP extension on Centos 5?

Tags: centos, centos5, pecl

Can anyone advise me if it is possible to install the Imagick PHP extension on CentOS 5, running PHP 5.3, and if so, how?

When I try to use pecl to install Imagick using

```
sudo pecl install imagick
```

I get an error stating that the package requires PHP greater than 5.4

I realise that I am working with a fairly old system but that's unavoidable at the moment. Is it possible to get a version that will run with PHP5.3?

Comment: How did you get PHP 5.3 on the system? Standard is 5.1 on CentOS 5. If you can update to a newer version, try the [Remi repo](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/), he offers both PHP 5.4 and the fitting Imagick for it.

Comment: Hi @Sven - at the moment I'm using [this Vagrant box](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=centos+cully) as it's more or less a duplicate of the server I am developing a script for. As the owner will not update their version of PHP since it will introduce breaking changes to other things that are running on there, I would need to get imagick to work on PHP5.3.3

Comment: You're stuck. PHP 5.3 is past end of support, and you should have migrated away from it years ago. I don't know if this can be done at all at this late date.